# Floating Elements in background reactive to mousemove

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation, gsap

Hy,

I'm trying to replicate this kind of effect https://2016.oneis.us/ . I'm stuck with the BG animation. I have seen that this effect runs also on mobile devices. If someone knows how to program this and what kind of JS libraries I need, please link me a tutorial or some useful links.

Thank's!!!

Answer (score 0):

You don't **need** frameworks, they just make it easier.

You can use:

- P5.js
- Three.js
- Particles.js

Answer (score 0):

Just for fun and maybe a starter for you :)

```js
var frameRate = 60;
particles = [], x = 100, y = 100;


function handleMouseMove(event) {
  x = scene.offsetWidth / 2 - event.pageX;
  y = scene.offsetHeight / 2 - event.pageY;
};

function animate() {
  particles.forEach((p) => {
    p.move();
  });
};

function startAnimation() {
  this.timelineId = setInterval(animate, frameRate);
};

function stopAnimation() {
  clearInterval(this.timelineId);
};

function createParticle(src) {
  var img = document.createElement('img');

  img.src = src;
  img.width = 50 + Math.random() * 50;
  return new Particle(img);
};

function addToScene(scene, particle) {
  scene.appendChild(particle.img);
  particle.img.style.left = 100 * Math.random() + '%';
  particle.y = particle.dy = scene.offsetHeight + particle.img.offsetHeight;
  particles.push(particle);
};

function Particle(img) {
  this.img = img;
  this.dx = 0;
  this.dy = 0;
};

Particle.prototype.move = function() {
  this.dy -= 1 + y / 100;
  this.dx = x/2;
  if (this.dy < -4 * this.img.offsetHeight) {
    this.dy = this.y;
  }

  var s = `translate(${this.dx}px, ${this.dy}px)`;

  this.img.style.transform = s;
};

const scene = document.getElementById('scene');
var i = 0,
  id = setInterval(function() {
    if (i++ > 10) {
      clearInterval(id);
    }
    var p = createParticle('https://2016.oneis.us/images/0.png');
    addToScene(scene, p);
  }, 1000);

scene.onmousemove = handleMouseMove;



startAnimation();
```

```css
* {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#scene {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: 999;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

#scene img {
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<h3>What is Lorem Ipsum?</h3>
<p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has
  survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing
  software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
<div id="scene"></div>
```